# How do i show a selectbox when it is in <p> and i do p.text("test") in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

In am working with MVC and i want to show a selectbox

```
   <p id="selectedTrigger">
       <select name="devices" id="devices"><!-- Here i get the options with javascript --></select>
   </p>
```

If i do this it works, but when i do in javascript the next line of code:

```
    $('#selectedTrigger').text("TEST");
```

It doesn't show the selectbox anymore, only the text TEST

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Thats because when you call .text("TEST"); it replaces the content fo the <p id="selectedTrigger">

Comment: What do you want to do? show TEST after the selectbox?

Comment: Maybe you want to append the text "TEST" to the p ? try $("#selectedTrigger").append("TEST") instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is you replace everything between `<p id="selectedTrigger">` and `</p>`. If you are using jQuery then use `.html()` method to replace content inside it or use `.append()` to add content inside your `<p>`.

So in your instance you would have to say:

```
$('#selectedTrigger').append("TEST");
```

Note that this will result in following code:

```
<p ...>
  <select ..></select>
  TEST
</p>
```

There is also .prepend() method that allows you to append content before any content you already have.

```
$('#selectedTrigger').prepend("TEST");
```

This would give you:

```
<p ...>
  TEXT
  <select ..></select>
</p>
```

**Solution:**
But since you are trying to add options to your `<select>` inside your `<p>` you should really use this:

```
$('#devices').append("TEST");
```

This will give you:

```
<p ...>
  <select ..>
    TEST
  </select>
</p>
```

Comment: @TomHorwood There we go : )

Comment: Thanks @kellax with .html it works fine and i could remove a bunch of lines